# Variable privada no se actualiza aunque sus componentes sí?

Tags: java

El siguiente código calcula el *finalPrice* de una hamburguesa en base a su *basePrice* y *additionalsPrice* (si es que los hay).

La variable *precioBase* es definida al principio y siempre la misma ($10), y la variable *precioAdicionales* se actualiza correctamente en el caso de que se agreguen adicionales (el método no lo pongo porque excede caracteres permitidos).

El problema es que el *precioFinal* (que es compuesta por las otras dos) siempre muestra el valor definido por default como *precioBase* . Por qué?

Encima, si hago printout de precioBase+precioAdicionales, el calculo es correcto. Solo es incorrecto si pido que imprima precioFinal (que es compuesta por las otras dos).

```
public class Hamburger {

private String name = "Basic hamburger";
private String bread;
private String meat;
private double basePrice = 10;
private double additionalsPrice = 0;
private double finalPrice = (basePrice + additionalsPrice);

public Hamburger(String bread, String meat) {
        this.bread = bread;
        this.meat = meat;
    }

public void additionals(){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Select up to 4 additionals for your burger \n" +
            "1. TOMATE (add $2) \n" +
            "2. LECHUGA (add $1,25 \n" +
            "3. CHEDDAR (add $2,25 \n" +
            "4. PANCETA (add $3,75");

            for(int f = 1; f<5; f++){
                System.out.println("Select addition # " + f + " or choose a number > 4 to exit");
            int selection = scanner.nextInt();

            switch(selection){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("TOMATE added to your burger \n");
                    this.additionalsPrice += 2;
                    tomate = true;
                    additionals = true;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("LECHUGA added to your burger \n");
                    this.additionalsPrice += 1.25;
                    lechuga = true;
                    additionals = true;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("CHEDDAR added to your burger \n");
                    this.additionalsPrice += 2.25;
                    cheddar = true;
                    additionals = true;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("PANCETA added to your burger \n");
                    this.additionalsPrice += 3.75;
                    panceta = true;
                    additionals = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("No more additionals added \n");
                    f = 100; //numero mayor que 4 termina el loop
            }




            }





}

    public void getTheFinalPrice() {
    System.out.println("YOUR FINAL PRICE:");
    System.out.println("BASE PRICE for your burger is " + basePrice);
    if(additionals){
    System.out.println("ADDITIONALS price for your burger is: " + additionalsPrice);
    getAdditionals();
    } else {
        System.out.println("No additionals");
    }
    System.out.println("FINAL PRICE for your burger is: " + (basePrice + additionalsPrice));

}
```

Comment: puedes agregar el código completo para poder ayudarte

Comment: Tú haces una asignación a `finalPrice` cuando lo declaras, pero luego en la clase no se ve que el campo sea modificado en ninguna parte. ¿De qué forma obtienes el precio final en la lógica de tu programa? Yo veo errores lógicos en tu clase. De entrada, esa asignación no sirve de mucho en la declaración. En las clases se suelen inicializar con valores aquellos campos constantes que nunca cambian. Luego, tienes un *getter* que no devuelve nada ¿?

Comment: finalPrice está compuesta por basePrice + additionalsPrice. En la medida que se agregan adicionales (agregué el metodo que hace eso para que sea mas claro) la variable additionalsPrice cambia, por ende debería cambiar finalPrice, pero no lo hace.

Comment: No. `finalPrice` copia los valores que tienen `basePrice` + `additionalPrices`. No se crea una especia de enlace entre las variables para que se actualice una cuando cambia la otra.

Comment: En el código que muestras `finalPrice` nunca cambia de valor. Revísalo bien. Y la lógica de tu clase es confusa, no puedes tener un *getter* que no devuelve nada. Pregunto de nuevo, **¿cómo sacas `finalPrice` de la clase?** y **¿cómo modificas `finalPrice` en la clase, dónde?** Enséñanos en qué líneas ocurre eso, yo no lo veo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La variable `finalPrice` se inicializa cuando se crea el objeto y luego no cambia su valor. Se inicializa con los valores que tienen `basePrice` y `additionalsPrice` al momento de crear el objeto (10 + 0).

Para que la variable cambie, se debe actualizar cada vez que se cambia el valor de `basePrice` o de `additionalsPrice`.

Como se trata de un valor calculado, el cúal no cuesta mucho, deberías realizarlo en el método `getTheFinalPrice` y no almacenarla en una variable privada:

```
public class Hamburger {

private String name = "Basic hamburger";
private String bread;
private String meat;
private double basePrice = 10;
private double additionalsPrice = 0;
//private double finalPrice = (basePrice + additionalsPrice);

public Hamburger(String bread, String meat) {
   this.bread = bread;
   this.meat = meat;
}

public double getTheFinalPrice() {

    double finalPrice = 0.00;

    System.out.println("YOUR FINAL PRICE:");
    System.out.println("BASE PRICE for your burger is " + basePrice);
    if(additionals){
    System.out.println("ADDITIONALS price for your burger is: " + additionalsPrice);
     getAdditionals();
     } else {
         System.out.println("No additionals");
     }

    finalPrice = this.basePrice + this.additionalsPrice;

    System.out.println("FINAL PRICE for your burger is: " + finalPrice);
}}
```

Desconozco lo que hace `getAdditionals`. Lo anterior se basa en el supuesto de que, al final del método, `basePrice` y `additionalsPrice` tendrán los valores que les corresponden.

Saludos.

Comment: Agregué el método que calcula y actualiza el precio de los adicionales. Sigo sin entender por qué actualiza el precio de las variables additionalsPrice pero no el de finalPrice que es compuesta por esta última + precioBase.

Comment: Cómo lo tienes ahora, se le asigna su valor cuando se crea y queda con ese hasta que hagas `finalPrice = otroValor`. Lo que tenés es igual a colocar `finalPrice = 10` y nunca modificarlo

Comment: Gracias! Ya lo entendí y lo pude corregir.